# CSS3 valid 'opacity' for <=IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I'm trying to ensure that my companies website is HTML5/CSS3 valid, but I've hit a problem with one little piece of CSS.

Basically, we have a filtered list of Team members (a picture of each with a name/email underneath), with those who are out of scope placed at the end and slightly faded (`opacity: 0.3;`). However, with IE8 (and before) being special, I used the following -

```
filter: alpha(opacity=30);
```

This however caused a validation error "Parse Error opacity=30)", so I done some searching and replaced it with this -

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
```

No error this time, but I do get a warning - "Property -ms-filter is an unknown vendor extension"

Does anybody know of a CSS3 valid way of applying `opacity` that is backwards compatible with IE8 (I.e. no errors or warnings)? Thanks.

Comment: Vendor extension warnings can be disregarded. Really. Trust me.

Comment: This is the only way of achieving `opacity` in IE 8 and lower (there are a lot of things that are not "standard" in these browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Well one way would be to simply add an additional effect alongside the opacity. This way browsers which do not render the `opacity` property are still able to differentiate the team members who are out of scope:

```css
selector {
    background: #dfdfdf;    /* New property, light grey background. */
    opacity: 0.3;           /* Old existing property, no validation warnings. */
}
```

Comment: Ordinarily I'd agree, but in this instance I my selector is a image, so it's difficult to apply any such effect in this case. Thanks.